# sum of squares (4 values shaping a square) within a 2d numpy array. Python

Tags: python, numpy

I am looking to sum each 4 point combination in a 2d array that forms squares within the matrix

```
in4x4 = np.array(([1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,1],[3,4,1,2],[4,3,1,2]))
print(in4x4)
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [2, 3, 4, 1],
       [3, 4, 1, 2],
       [4, 3, 1, 2]])
```

Expected output:

```
print(out3x3)
array([[ 8, 12, 12],
       [12, 12,  8],
       [14,  9,  6]]
```

Currently I am using `numpy.diff` in a several step process. Feel like there should be a cleaner approach. Example of the calculation I currently do:

```
diff3x4 = np.diff(a4x4,axis=0)
a3x4 = a4x4[0:3,:] * 2 + d3x4
d3x3 = np.diff(a3x4)
a3x3 = a3x4[:,0:3] * 2 + d3x3
```

Is there a clean possibly vectorized approach? Speed is of concern. Looked at `scipy.convolve` but does not seem to suit my purposes, but maybe I am just configuring the kernel wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do 2-D convolution with a kerenl of ones to achieve the desired result.

Simple code that implements 2D-convolution and test on the input you gave:

```
import numpy as np

def conv2d(a, f):
    s = f.shape + tuple(np.subtract(a.shape, f.shape) + 1)
    strd = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided
    subM = strd(a, shape = s, strides = a.strides * 2)
    return np.einsum('ij,ijkl->kl', f, subM)

in4x4 = np.array(([1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,1],[3,4,1,2],[4,3,1,2]))
k = np.ones((2,2))

print(conv2d(in4x4, k))
```

output:

```
[[ 8. 12. 12.]
 [12. 12.  8.]
 [14.  9.  6.]]
```

In case you can use built-in function you can use  like in the following:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
in4x4 = np.array(([1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,1],[3,4,1,2],[4,3,1,2]))
k = np.ones((2,2))
signal.convolve2d(in4x4, k, 'valid')
```

Which output:

```
array([[ 8., 12., 12.],
       [12., 12.,  8.],
       [14.,  9.,  6.]])
```

signal.convolve2d(in4x4, k, 'valid')

Comment: Thank you that is 95% it. But how do I express the shape of k programmatically.
If it is half the dimensions of in4x4, then it will only work for even number shapes?
like:
k = np.ones((int(in4x4.shape[0]/2),int(in4x4.shape[1]/2))). ??

Speaking about the 2nd approach

Comment: What does it mean determine `k` programmatically? You would still need to convolve but might need to play with the parameter of `convolve2d`

Comment: I meant that in my real application, it is not a 4x4 array so I need to calculate k based on the actual shape, which might change.
np.ones((int(in4x4.shape[0]/2),int(in4x4.shape[1]/2))). this seemed clumsy but seems to work with differently sized arrays.